# Moving back to parent view controller or dismissing child view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

On click of a button, I am navigating from one controller to another. I was initially doing `self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)` and it was covering the whole window on the device. Since I wanted it to be of the size of my main (presenting) controller, below is the code that I use now to present new controller.

***Navigating to NewViewController from Parent Controller:***

```
@IBAction func doneButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewID") as! NewViewController
        nextViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        nextViewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        self.view.addSubview(nextViewController.view)
        self.addChild(nextViewController)
        nextViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        //self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

This works fine and navigates me to NewViewController controller. But now from NewViewController controller, I wish to come back to this parent controller for which my dismiss logic is not working.

***Going back from NewViewController to Parent Controller***

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What am I missing? How do I go back to the parent controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually had to do to present over the entire window was to modify `modalPresentationStyle` property of `nextViewController`.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewID") as! NewViewController
nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Add this code to `doneButtonAction` and present it the old way.